How to get classnames with a site in categories/subcategories?
I'm trying to get only the classnames of each level of this site. What I mean with levels? Well, the structure of the site it has 3 or 4 levels or it shows the information in categories and subcategories and is needed to drilldown to go deeper.
The structure is:

In initial URL, the site shows links of each state (let say level 1)
When click on any state, it opens another url and shows one or more cities in each state (level 2)
When click on any city, it opens another url and shows one or more locations in each city (level 3)
Finally, when open details of each location, it shows the address of each location (level 4)

Below is my current code with which I've been able to get the classname of the first 3 levels, but having issues with 4th level, getting this error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. My logic is find the link (anchor html element) for the state given (in this case Alabama). When that element that contains Alabama is found, I get the classname. The same applies for city, location.
*Is important for me not to use xpath in this process.
May someone could help me to enhance/fix my code in order to get the address classname and how to handle when there is only 3 levels. Would be 4 levels when the city has more than one location. If the city has only one location, there would be only 3 levels. Below an image that shows the classnames when the input has a city with more than one location (Huntsville/4 levels) and a city with only one location (Birmingham/3 levels).

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


# function to get url and class in different levels
def get_url_class(url,level):
    driver.get(url) 
    time.sleep(3)
    links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    
    for lnk in links:
        if level in lnk.text:
            if lnk.get_attribute("class"):
                new_class = lnk.get_attribute("class")
                new_url = lnk.get_attribute("href")
                return [new_class,new_url]


#  Open chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Defining texts to search for each element
state="Alabama"    # --> Level #1
city="Huntsville"  # --> Level #2
location="South Memorial Pkwy, Huntsville"  # --> Level #3
address="11375 South Memorial Pkwy"  # --> Level #4

initial_url = "https://locations.bojangles.com/"

# Level #1 (Get state´s url and class)
level1 = get_url_class(initial_url,state)
print("className:" + level1[0] + ", url: "+ level1[1])

# Level #2 (Get cities´ url and class)
level2 = get_url_class(level1[1],city)
print("className:" + level2[0] + ", url: "+ level2[1])

# Level #3 (Get location's url and class)
level3 = get_url_class(level2[1],location)
print("className:" + level3[0] + ", url: "+ level3[1])

# Level #4 (Get address' url and class)
level4 = get_url_class(level3[1],address)
print("className:" + level4[0] + ", url: "+ level4[1])


driver.quit()

